# C++ dll framework issue

Tags: visual-c++

I am very much new to stack overflow so I do apologize if I make some mistakes with following this forums conventions.

I was wandering if any of the professional C++ coders on this site had some ideas for a current problem I have with my existing code within visual C++ 2010.

Is there an easier way to share classes, members and functions between two dynamically loaded dll's without the use of having to use a ton of GetProcAdress() functions.

For anyone who reads or replies to this; thank you for your time and help.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this example:
[How to export an instantiation of a Standard Template Library (STL) class and a class that contains a data member that is an STL object](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/168958)

Comment: Thank you for the reply I will take an in depth look at this.